# How to submit a form with related model data in ember-data 1.0?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm creating a record from both form data and another promise (for the related record).

Here is the basic JSON I'm centered around

```
//appointment
{
  "id": 6,
  "details": "test",
  "customer": 1
}

//customer
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Sle eep",
  "appointments": [6]
}
```

My ember-data models look like this

```
App.Appointment = DS.Model.extend({
  details: attr('string'),
  customer: belongsTo('customer', { async: true})
});

App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  appointments: hasMany()
});
```

When I create an appointment it currently looks something like this

```
this.store.find('customer', 1).then(function(customer) {
  var appointment = {
    details: 'foo',
    customer: customer.get('id')
  }
  this.store.createRecord('appointment', appointment).save();
});
```

The problem with the above is that my serializer doesn't do well when the form data is a promise. Is this how I should be creating records? If not, what should this create look like?

Thank you in advance

**Update**

After a little more looking around, it seems the async: true on belongsTo might be the issue. Just before the "createRecord" I can see the following

> Object {details: "asd", customer: 1}

But when I jump into the "createRecord" method of ember-data (in the RESTAdapter) I notice that now customer is represented as a promise again (not the integer value or string value I saw just before that method was invoked)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you wait for the find to be resolved before creating the record and sending?

```
var self = this,
    promise = this.store.find('customer', 1); //just to show it's a promise

promise.then(function(customer){

  var appointment = {
    details: 'foo',
    customer: customer
  }
  self.store.createRecord('appointment', appointment).save();
},{
  alert("uh oh end of the world, couldn't find customer");
});
```

Async isn't extremely well documented and seems to have some willy-nilly side-effects (It is all still in beta, so no major judgement from me yet).  That being said, your appointments hasMany isn't defined, here's a playground for this.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OlaRagux/5/edit

Comment: I've added a little more detail above -seems the async: true might be part of the issue in this example

Comment: yeah, I wouldn't doubt it, async is a little wonky, see updated answer.

Comment: I've created an issue w/ ember-data as it looks like a bug in the library as you mentioned https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1542